# PHP : Not able to fetch google photos/album using API

Tags: php, google-photos-api

Sharing below code what i have tried:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("XXX");
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->getAccessToken();

$service = new Google_Service_PhotosLibrary($client);
$response = $service->albums->listAlbums($client);
```

I am getting below error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code":
>   401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication
>   credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
>   authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
>   "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global",
>   "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType":
>   "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }

Sharing below github lib i am using to integrate google photos.
Github Google API : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: Where is `credentials.json` in relation to the code in question? Also you do not appear to be setting up the access token at all. Have you looked at [the example here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php)? Specifically around the access token setup.

Comment: @segFault: in example you suggested, from where we will get "token.json"?

Comment: I believe that is just a local cache example, it would be something you generate, see the else block where it gets written to in the example script.